# Mouse listener to get point's position on a trace

Tags: java, swing

I have built a GUI. It has a chart panel and consists of a trace. Now I need to design a mouse listener in such a way that when I click over the trace, a point should be displayed over the gui chart panel. For that my code is like this. It is showing error. It would be grateful if it is clarified.

```
package jchart2Dt;

import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import info.monitorenter.gui.chart.traces.Trace2DSimple;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MouseEvents extends Jchart2Dt_GUI{
    public static void listener () {


    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            if(event instanceof MouseEvent){
                MouseEvent evt = (MouseEvent)event;
                if(evt.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED){

                    float x=(float)getX(trace_0);
                    float y=(float)getY(trace_0);
                    System.out.println(x+","+y);
                }
            }
        }

        private float getY(Trace2DSimple trace_0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return NTRACES;
            //return 0;
        }
    }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);

}

    protected static float getX(Trace2DSimple trace_0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return NTRACES;
        //return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: it is printing (1.0,1.0) on the console where ever i click with the mouse but i need the co-ordinates of the trace to be printed when i click on the trace inside my chart

Comment: To know where the click occured, you are supposed to call `getX()` and `getY()` on the `MouseEvent` object.

Comment: i should write a method for getX() and getY() and so i have method as you see in the snippet but i have a doubt near return NTRACES which is wrong, so what can i do in order to return x-coordinate and y-coordinate for the methods getX() and getY()

Comment: Why in the world are you using the `Toolkit` to add a generic global listener instead of registering a `MouseListener` on the chart `Panel`?

Comment: I tried using MouseListener, it is not working on it so i tried in this way , if the MouseListener works , it is fine ... if u can help me writing it

Comment: The listener that receives an event is supposed to have the knowledge  and means to handle it appropriately.  You want your listener object to perform whatever state changes are necessary so that the desired point is painted when the GUI is repainted, and probably to schedule a repaint.  The details of that are highly specific to your GUI details.

Comment: okay i will try using MouseListener in correct way, thankyou

Comment: I have used mouse listener now .. but it is giving the coordinates as x= 2 and y= 18 where ever i pressed... I am not knowing ;why is it showing only these two values. @JohnBollinger

Comment: "Using a MouseListener" is in no way enough information for anyone to explain why you observe the behavior you do.  Do carefully consider my immediately previous comment, however: although a `MouseListener` registered on the correct component is the right tool for the job, it is even more important to use that tool the right way, and my comment provides an overview of that way.  It differs tremendously from what you are actually doing in the code you presented.

Comment: okay thankyou, i got it